# Google PlusOne Button has errors on Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-api, google-plus-one

Google PlusOne has errors on Chrome:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: iframes is not defined fastbutton:19
Uncaught ReferenceError: iframes is not defined fastbutton:19
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'plusones' of undefined (program):66
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'hefn' fastbutton:16
```

the [not-so-]funny part is that it works on IE and on FireFox.

I should also add that it was working for a while properly and I only see these errors now.  not sure what has changed.

any ideas?  TIA

p.s. I also have jQuery and a bare bone Modernizr on that page.

Comment: I'm getting this too.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's possible that you have 3rd party cookies blocked. To test this on my Chrome (Version  26.0.1410.43) I added exceptions for :-

- apis.google.com
- plusone.google.com
- clients6.google.com
- gstatic.com

After that the +1 button worked for me.

Regards,

Dan

Comment: I _do_ have 3rd party cookies blocked, but until recently it the Google+ button was working properly with that setting enabled.  also, the FB Like, Tweet, and PinIt buttons work properly with those cookies disabled.  surely Google can do at least as well as those other Social Networks?

Comment: looks like the only exception needed for this button was for: plusone.google.com -- thank you!