# Google plus badge not showing

Tags: javascript, html, google-plus

I create a Badge on Google plus developers : https://developers.google.com/+/web/badge/
but when I copy and past the code into my HTML file the badge not showing. Here is my code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Google + Badge</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <!-- Place this tag where you want the widget to render. -->
    <div class="g-page" data-href="https://plus.google.com/109600806421917664383" data-rel="publisher"></div>

    <!-- Place this tag after the last widget tag. -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
      (function() {
        var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
        po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
      })();
    </script>


  </body>
</html>
```

What I'm doing wrong !? Thanks

Comment: The posted code seems to be working fine in a [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ed5XF/), so that's probably not the issue, and that makes it hard to tell what the issue is, but it's probably something else on your site.

Answer (score 0):

[adeneo's JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ed5XF/) wasn't working for me either (Chrome 35, OSX). First I had to whitelist it in the [Disconnect extension](https://disconnect.me/). Then I was getting the console error

```
Uncaught ReferenceError iframes is not defined
```

which, according to http://www.jesse-smith.net/fixed-google-plus-1-button-working/ and [Google PlusOne Button has errors on Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15214781/google-plusone-button-has-errors-on-chrome), is caused by having 3rd-party cookies blocked.

If you're using Chrome as well (and the problem is caused for you by blocking 3rd-party cookies as well), there should be a cookie icon on the right-hand side of your URL bar. Click it, click "Show cookies and other site data...", change to the "Blocked" tab and allow all the 3rd-party cookies from *.google.com domains.

You can also go Settings > Show advanced settings > Privacy, click the “Content Settings” button and enable 3rd-party cookies everywhere.

Unfortunately I wasn't able to find a way to get your G+ button to work in browsers with 3rd-party cookies disabled.

Comment: I'm using Chrome as well, and just tested on a new setup, and the default setting in all browsers is not block those cookies, so you fiddled with some setting that 99.99% of internet users wouldn't fiddle with, and you assume that's the issue? It could well be that this is the OP's issue, but statistically the chances are slim.

Comment: I don't assume it is the issue, just that it could be. From what I found in Google, it seemed to be a fairly common cause. And, yes, 99.99% of internet users have probably never change that setting, but OP is a developer and probably knows better. OP hasn't given us enough information to narrow it down further, so this is the best I can do. Are we not supposed to do that? The help center says to give a "partial answer" in these situations so I figured it would be ok.

Comment: Nope, no downvotes here, the answer is probably fine, just noting that it seems unlikely that the issue is just that the OP changed some setting in the browser and forgot about it, but I really have no idea, so again, could well be that this is it ?