# Hiding a close button from a Jquery Modal Window

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap-3, jquery-ui-dialog

[image]Attached the code that I am using for Pop Up Modal window which generates two close buttons

I am trying to hide the Close button generated from iFrame.

```
   jQuery(document.body).append('<div id="dialogDivWindow"></div>');

   jQuery("#dialogDivWindow").html('<iframe id="dialogFrameWindow" width="900" 

   height="500" marginWidth="0" marginHeight="0" frameBorder="0" close="no" 

   src="about:blank" />');

   jQuery("#dialogDivWindow").dialog({      
    height: 'auto',
    width: 950,
    modal: true,
    resizable: false,
    draggable: false,
    autoOpen: false,
    buttons:[
             {
                 text: "Close",
                 icons: { primary: "ui-icon-closethick" },
                 id: "closebtn",
                 click: function() { 
                     var $this = jQuery(this); 
                     $this.dialog("close"); 

                 }
             }
         ],
    open: function() {
                jQuery(this).closest(".ui-dialog").find(
                ".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").removeClass(
                "ui-dialog-titlebar-close").html(
                "<span class='fa fa-times fa-lg'></span>");

         }
  });
  jQuery("#dialogFrameWindow").attr("src", url);
  jQuery("#dialogDivWindow").dialog("open");
```

This Modal Pop Up generates two Close Buttons.

How can I avoid the close button which generates from iFrame.

In Picture I would like to hide the first 'Close' button.

anything can be done using Jquery

Comment: So which button do you want to remove, the one from jQuery UI? or one within the iframe itself? I don't see any "close" button when I create an `iframe` element.

Comment: Yes , I dont know why i get close button from iFrame, I am looking to hide the close button from iFrame

Comment: Is the iframe loading an actual external page? If so, does it have the close button if loaded directly in browser? However it's rendered, its going to depend on if the iframe "server" can be passed arguments

Answer (score 2):

Remove `close='no'` within `iframe` tag.. should work

Comment: can u give a screenshot ??

Answer (score 0):

Edit the portion. Might help u.  add this => 
type:iframe,
showCloseButton:false

if not works. also try  showCloseButton:hide instead of  showCloseButton:false

```
 jQuery("#dialogDivWindow").dialog({      
    height: 'auto',
    width: 950,
    modal: true,
    resizable: false,
    draggable: false,
    autoOpen: false,
    type   : iframe,
    showCloseButton:false
    buttons:[
             {
                 text: "Close",
                 icons: { primary: "ui-icon-closethick" },
                 id: "closebtn",
                 click: function() { 
                     var $this = jQuery(this); 
                     $this.dialog("close"); 

                 }
             }
         ],
    open: function() {
                jQuery(this).closest(".ui-dialog").find(
                ".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").removeClass(
                "ui-dialog-titlebar-close").html(
                "<span class='fa fa-times fa-lg'></span>");

         }
  });
```

Comment: When i add iframe the error i get "Uncaught ReferenceError: iframe is not defined "

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15214781/google-plusone-button-has-errors-on-chrome

take a look.. might be helpful